# Proving conditional probability sequence using the sum rule

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given the probability:
$$p(a,b,c)=p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$$

How to prove
$$
    p(a,b)=p(a)\sum_{c}p(c|a)p(b|c)=p(a)p(b|a)
$$

Does anyone have idea how to prove the above sequence?
I am confused how is the sum rule applied.

Comment: This is not true in general. If $c$ and $b$ are independent, you'll have $p(b) = p(b|a)$, which implies than $a$ and $b$ are independent, too. The formula is correct if and only if $b$ depends on $a$ through $c$, that is $p(b|a,c) = p(b|c)$.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Sorry I haven't given all conditions. I editted once again. Would you please give me some inspiration? Thanks a lot^_^

Comment: Ok, then just note that $p(a,b,c) = p(b,c|a) p(a) $ (by definition) which leads to $ p(b,c|a) = p(c|a) p(b|c)$ (from the first statement). The right-hand side of the last equation is what you have in the sum, so the sum is equal to $\sum_c p(b,c|a)$. This is [marginalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) over $c$.

Comment: Thats really helpful, thanks a lot! Would you please tell me how did you come up with that idea! I was looking at this like half hour notching my head :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiple applications of the [conditional probabilty rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability) you get:

$$p(a,b) = \sum_{c} p(a,b,c) = \sum_{c} p(b,c|a) p(a) = p(a) \sum_{c} p(b,c|a) = p(a) \sum_{c} p(b|a,c) p(c|a).$$

This is as far as you can actually go without more assumptions.    In the special case where $b \text{ } \bot \text{ } a | c$ (i.e., $b$ is conditionally independent of $a$ given $c$) you have $p(b|a,c) = p(b|c)$ which gives you the desired result.